# Cloudinary image not displaying Invalid URL

Tags: heroku, cloudinary

I'm using cloudinary to store an image and Imagemagick to upload. The image uploadde successfully, as I can see it on my cloudinary dashboard, but it doesn't display on the page. It gives the following error. This is a heroku app

Invalid URL
http://dhwgznjct-res-3.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_fit,h_48,w_48/sktx7wflb9ewtg6zypu4.png

The requested URL "http://%5bNo%20Host%5d/image/upload/c_fit,h_240,w_240/sktx7wflb9ewtg6zypu4.png", is invalid.
Reference #9.9d086a7c.1504157220.4809d0a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is configured for private CDN (i.e., `cloudname-res.cloudinary.com`), The URL works in the original setup - 
http://res.cloudinary.com/dhwgznjct/image/upload/c_fit,h_48,w_48/sktx7wflb9ewtg6zypu4.png

Check your environment settings and remove the `private_cdn:true` (or set to `false`).